# What does this error mean?

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am writing a C++ code in the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) platform. I am getting the following error:

```
*** Break *** segmentation violation
gdb not found, need it for stack trace
Root > Function main() busy flag cleared
```

I just want to know what this means (in general).

Comment: Segmentation violation - usually some kind of memory access error (pointer run amok). gdb not found - This is the gnu debugger. It appears not to be installed or is not in the system path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically that means you have written to (or maybe read) memory you don't have permission on. Either it's just invalid memory or (if the platform supports such a concept) it's outside of the memory you own.

A common cause of this is freeing a pointer but then using it again.

```
Foo * pFoo = new Foo();
pFoo->Bar(); // should be fine.
delete pFoo; // pFoo now points to memory that may or may not still be an actual Foo.
pFoo->Bar(); // undefined behavior.
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, "segmentation violation" means you accessed a piece of memory that wasn't allocated to you. Usually a stray pointer is the reason for that.

The remaining is some Linux-specific message concerning a missing gdb (which would be helpful to understand the problem).